# Using icons in Bootstrap 4.5

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, icons

I'm trying to figure out how to use the icons in Bootstrap 4.5 via CSS. Are there any code examples you can point me to? Ideally I'd like to know what CSS declarations are needed to be able to use them like Font Awesome e.g. 
`<i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>`.

The documentation at bootstrap https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#usage is not sufficient for me to figure out how to use them in a similar fashion. In other words, I'd like to be able to use jquery to set a class on an object to add an icon dynamically but I don't understand the CSS I need to do this.

Comment: Did you ever get a working answer for this?   I can get font-awesome fonts to work, but the Bootstrap4 classes don't show the icons!  This is driving me bonkers!

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
.bi-headphones::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='1em' height='1em' viewBox='0 0 16 16' class='bi bi-headphones' fill='currentColor' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M8 3a5 5 0 0 0-5 5v4.5H2V8a6 6 0 1 1 12 0v4.5h-1V8a5 5 0 0 0-5-5z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M11 10a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2v4a1 1 0 0 1-1 1h-1a1 1 0 0 1-1-1v-3zm-6 0a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H2v4a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h1a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-3z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1rem 1rem; 
  width:1rem; height:1rem;
}
```

Usage:

```
<i class="bi-headphones"></i>
```

I use URl SVG encoder to prepare svg for css: https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/

Answer (score -1):

i cant find in the doc that bootstrap icon is fontawesome icon
after you install it you use it as a svg like this one

```
<svg class="bi bi-app" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M11 2H5a3 3 0 0 0-3 3v6a3 3 0 0 0 3 3h6a3 3 0 0 0 3-3V5a3 3 0 0 0-3-3zM5 1a4 4 0 0 0-4 4v6a4 4 0 0 0 4 4h6a4 4 0 0 0 4-4V5a4 4 0 0 0-4-4H5z"/>
</svg>
```

or you can use it this way after you download the svg to you project

```
<img src="/assets/img/bootstrap.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" title="Bootstrap">
```

or on your css

```
.bi::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23333' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path fill-rule='evenodd' d='M8 9.5a1.5 1.5 0 1 0 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 3z' clip-rule='evenodd'/></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1rem 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have seen the documentation but I don't understand how to go from these exmaples to set up CSS so that I can assign the svg to a class such as "myicon."  Then I would like to be able to use that class to do something like <button><span class="myicon"></span></button>.

Comment: the simples way is download the icon pack from here https://github.com/twbs/icons/archive/v1.0.0-alpha4.zip then copy the icons folder to your project then load it just like image <button><img src="/assets/img/bootstrap.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" title="Bootstrap">
</button>

Comment: My goal is to be able to dynamically change the icon on a button. Imagine an audio player where the play/pause symbols alternate after a click. I was thinking to do this via a CSS class but if there is another way to do it that would be ok too.

Comment: same problem here. What exact folder are they supposed to go into? there's no indication in the bootstrap.css as to where it is actually looking for the icons.